# My USB drive is not working

Tags: usb-drive, format

I inserted my Sandisk Cruzor Blade (4 GB) into my Ubuntu laptop few days ago and formatted it. And a message appeared: `unable to mount your drive`. Now when I insert the USB drive into it, it does not recognize it at all. Please help me to make the drive usable.

Comment: You can use a tool like `gparted` to look at the partitions and try formatting it again.

Comment: plugin your usb drive and then run `lsblk` command.Post it's output on your question.

Comment: I tried to run lsblk command in terminal and got the following output

Comment: NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 927.6G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   3.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1   3.8G  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1   3.9G  0 rom

Comment: It might be good to paste that into your question so it's a bit easier to read.

Comment: parted is a command line tool that can help (GUI is gparted)

Comment: Just i did was used parted and reallocated its memory now its working perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash drives sadly do not last forever, they can easily fail and become unusable or even unmountable...  Try your flash-drive in a different USB port, then in another computer entirely to make sure it is the flash-drive that's the problem..